# É possível usar o SQLite como cliente-servidor?

Tags: banco-de-dados, sqlite, engenharia-de-software, cliente-servidor

Existe qualquer técnica ou ferramenta para usar o SQLite utilizando uma arquitetura [Cliente-Servidor](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cliente-servidor) ao invés do acesso local?

Claro que precisaria de uma biblioteca cliente para se comunicar com o servidor. E uma aplicação servidora para tratar estas conexões e acessar o SQLite.

A dúvida é se existe algo pronto, confiável para usar, ou se tem alguma forma de fazer isso.

#### Um pouco de *background*

Algumas aplicações vão rodar em ambientes leves, com pouca concorrência e um perfil de, relativamente, baixo acesso, e essencialmente de leitura. O SQLite é mais que suficiente para atender esta demanda.

A única desvantagem é que o SQLite não é bom para receber acessos remotos concorrentes. Até funciona mas pode apresentar problemas. Eu sei que [oficialmente é recomendado não usar](http://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html) para este cenário. Mas esta recomendação é para o caso de compartilhar um arquivo em um servidor para acesso direto de múltiplas instâncias remotas.

Mas podemos ter um servidor que manipula as conexões e faz o acesso ao arquivo do SQLite localmente. Não há diferença para o uso em websites onde o Apache, IIS, etc. funcionam como o servidor, mesmo que indiretamente. Claro, você deve ter uma aplicação que recebe requisições de outras aplicações remotas (no *browser*), manipulá-las e enviar ao SQLite embutido nesta aplicação no servidor.

O SQlite tem a vantagem da manutenção zero. Nestes casos de baixo volume onde os usuários finais podem estar distantes para receberem manutenção e não dispõem de recursos para manter um técnico para administrar o DB, isso é inestimável.

---

Se alguém acha que não é uma boa solução, pense de novo.

No Brasil e em diversos países ainda temos uma quantidade incomensurável de sistemas desenvolvidos em [Clipper](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clipper_%28linguagem_de_programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o%29) ou [Harbour](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projeto_Harbour) que utilizam arquivos simples no formato `dbf` e funcionam em baixos volumes maravilhosamente bem. Na verdade já vi acesso de centenas de terminais funcionando sem grandes problemas (quando o sistema foi bem feito).

Note que o acesso ao `dbf` é semelhante ao SQLite. Cada aplicação remota acessa diretamente os arquivos compartilhados pela rede. E o sistema `dbf` não tem nem perto das características que o SQLite tem para dar confiabilidade. E nem estou falando do uso de tecnologias como o [LetoDB](http://sourceforge.net/projects/letodb/) que permite o acesso do `dbf` como cliente-servidor.

Muitas vezes as pessoas superestimam a necessidade de concorrência e subestimam tecnologias simples. O SQlite é uma evolução enorme em relação ao `dbf` (mesmo em Harbour, alguns programadores costumam usar DBs relacionais no lugar de `dbf` para aplicações novas).

Só falta a arquitetura cliente-servidor para o SQLite ficar perfeito para esses cenários.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A ferramenta [**SQL Relay**](http://sqlrelay.sourceforge.net/) - *middleware* que se interpõe entre os clientes HTTP e o(s) servidor(es) de banco de dados - [oferece suporte a SQLite](http://sqlrelay.sourceforge.net/sqlrelay/gettingstarted/sqlite.html). Através dela, é possível:

- Executar um *daemon* que aceita conexões locais e remotas (especificando endereço e porta);
- Criar uma instância que se conecta a um banco de dados SQLite (arquivo local ao servidor).

A ferramenta é bastante complexa para exibir um passo-a-passo aqui, mas pelo exemplo de configuração [no link acima]:

```xml
<instance id="sqlitetest" port="9000" socket="/tmp/sqlitetest.socket" dbase="sqlite"
          connections="3" maxconnections="5" maxqueuelength="0" growby="1" ttl="60"
          endofsession="commit" sessiontimeout="600" runasuser="testuser"
          runasgroup="testuser" cursors="5">
    <users>
        <user user="sqlitetest" password="sqlitetest"/>
    </users>
    <connections>
        <connection connectionid="sqlitetest" string="db=/usr/local/sqlite/var/testdb"
                    metric="1"/>
    </connections>
</instance>
```

Pode-se observar que:

1. Ela dá um "apelido" para o seu banco, para que os clientes externos o identifiquem;
2. Ela cria um nome de usuário e senha para garantir o acesso (suprindo a falta dos mesmos em uma instalação local);
3. Ela permite configurar vários parâmetros - como o número máximo de conexões, o *timeout*, etc - que podem assegurar que o banco não seja sobrecarregado com um excesso de conexões (importante, uma vez que o SQLite não foi feito para isso).

Observações:

- O SQLRelay pressupõe um ambiente *NIX (dá suporte a Cygwin), e possui licença GNU GPL 2 (não tenho certeza se essa informação está atualizada);
- Acessar o SQLite dessa forma **não elimina** todos os [problemas em potencial](http://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html). Por exemplo, ele continuará suportando apenas 1 escrita de cada vez. Entretanto, como apenas o servidor fará acesso direto a ele, o problema do "sistema de arquivos em rede" está resolvido.

  > A good rule of thumb is that you should avoid using SQLite in situations where the same database will be accessed simultaneously from many computers over a network filesystem.

  Tradução livre:

  > Via de regra, você deve evitar usar o SQLite em situações onde o mesmo banco de dados pode ser acessado simultaneamente a partir de vários computadores atrevés de um sistema de arquivos em rede.

Answer (score 4):

A pergunta está bem respondida, mas quero complementar que mesmo não usando uma solução pronta é fácil criar um pequeno servidor para acessar o SQLite.

A ideia é ter um executável rodando o tempo todo que embute o SQLite, talvez como um serviço/daemon, e que fará de fato os acessos ao banco na mesma máquina.

Este executável terá comunicação com o mundo externo por algum protocolo totalmente proprietário ou usando algo pronto. O TCP provavelmente será o preferido na maioria das situações. Existem bibliotecas prontas para lidar com os detalhes dele.

Obviamente precisará de um biblioteca para usar no lado do cliente que faça a conexão entre as duas partes. A biblioteca pode ser simples ou mais complexa, de acordo com a necessidade.

É possível até não precisar de nada se usar o HTTP como protocolo e seguir padrões web. O navegador será o cliente. Por isso em web o SQLite brilha muito.

Não que isto seja o mais recomendável mas é uma forma. Se for necessário é melhor seguir a arquitetura normalmente adotada e ter uma aplicação mais completa no lado do servidor que trate um nível acima a aplicação e não diretamente o protocolo HTTP.

Será necessário criar um formato de como os dados trafegarão entre o cliente e o servidor. Pode ser algo bem simples, binário ou textual, pode ser JSON, por exemplo, ou algo mais simples ainda. Se vai ter compactação, criptografia, vai da necessidade.

É, talvez seja melhor usar algo pronto. Mas se precisar é relativamente trivial fazer um servidor para usar o SQLite remotamente. Não é o acesso direto, mas resolve o problema, e existem várias vantagens em se fazer isto.

Claro que para fazer isto é preciso pensar um pouco fora da caixa. É preciso entender como as coisas funcionam e não apenas consumir coisas prontas. Ainda que usar o que já existe é ótimo também. Não pode fechar os olhos para outras soluções e aceitar que "não dá para fazer".

Eventualmente para criar um servidor assim pode-se aproveitar estas soluções prontas e extrair o que é mais importante delas.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 3):

Como você escreveu, não é recomendado que o SQLite seja utilizado com um servidor (já que ele é serveless), mas existem algumas formas de resolver:
Utilizar o [SQLitening](http://www.sqlitening.com)

**OU**

Você pode simular uma arquitetura cliente-servidor utilizando SSH, como no exemplo a seguir:

```
ssh user@host sqlite3 database SELECT * FROM table
```

Answer (score -2):

"É possível usar o SQLite como cliente-servidor?"
Literalmente a resposta é SIM desde que você saiba o que está fazendo e "não é um processo dito com simples".

Veja o que tenho a dizer:

1. Você conhece os requisitos da aplicação?
2. Você Entende e saber usar o Sqlite?

Se a resposta é sim para os dois, você sabe que o Sqlite tem problemas com concorrências, "Vários inserts/Escritas simultâneos"
Sabendo disso, não poderá gravar dados ao mesmo tempos, então sua aplicação não pode ser usando na forma tradicional  como esses sistemas de Desktop que acessa diretamente o banco de dados.

O que fazer?
Se você estudou estrutura de dados, "facilmente" você pode criar uma API com gerenciamento de FILA para solucionar esse problema de concorrências, todos o front acessar essa API e essa API vai gerenciar os pedidos de informação em uma FILA.

Em grosso modo você pode usar uma API como o adonisJs ou ao outra de sua preferencia desde que ela tenha um ORM que possa conectar com o SQlite, falo isso pois provavelmente você não vai querer cria isso na mão, e não, nãos sei dizer se eles usam algum esquema de FILA ou outro para gerencia múltiplas requisições com a conexão do banco Sqlite no controle de Escrita, então se isso não acontece, basta você fazer um gerenciamento de erro com resposta por exemplo de Timeout.
já foi relatado o uso do SQL Relay, mas se você não quer usar uma aplicação "ponte" criada por você, leia essa docuemntção sobre como SQL Relay:
https://sqlrelay.sourceforge.net/sqlrelay/admin/configguide.html

De qualquer forma será uma ponte entre suas aplicações e seu banco de
Sqlite...
Mas será se v ai valer a penas usa-lo na sua aplicações?

Então, não será um cliente-servido tradicional que "varias Aplicação acessa direto o banco" mas varias aplicações acessam uma ponte que controla o fluxo de entrada e saída, onde o controle maior será na escrita e não na leitura.

Limite do Sqlite: 128Tb.
Mais informações sobre o Sqlite está em:
https://www.sqlite.org/limits.html

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).