# É possivel criar um banco de informações em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, banco-de-dados

Há como criar um banco de dados simples sem utilizar um server?
Creio que a resposta seria não, porém verifiquem o seguinte:

- Estou no trabalho e não possuo acesso as bases de dados nem mesmos aos servidores.
  Desta forma consigo trabalhar somente na rede local e pastas compartilhadas.
- Não posso conectar USB na máquina e também não sou admin do computador.
- As informações que preciso armazenar são poucas e simples, sem a necessidade de utilizar um banco de dados.
- As pessoas que farão alterações ou inclusões nestas informações são um equipe de trabalho, não havendo possibilidades de edições simultâneas.
- Nem todos conseguem editar o código através do editor, devido a isso procurando outras formas de incluir informações na página.

A ideia seria criar um form simples no IE8, pois tenho acesso somente a ele.

- **HTML** : Possui dois forms um para inserção e outro que recebe as informações
- **Botão**: "Salvar" este executa um `documento1.js` que identifica os campos digitados e salva os campos em uma extensão qualquer.

O que eu tenho:

- Eu consigo armazenar pelo JavaScript as informações digitadas em um arquivo `.js` entre outros.
- Consigo salvar o arquivo como por exemplo `documento2.js`, dando um var para cada campo digitado, assim consigo identificar os campos depois.
- O `documento2.js` carrega no `head` do HTML, então qualquer atualização no documento dando um F5 o HTML terá acesso.

**O que me falta**:
Preciso que o form que retornará resultados reconheça automaticamente os campos no `documento2.js`.

```
<td name="recebe" id="Campo01">
(aqui o codigo que preciso para trazer um resultado que esteja no documento2.js com a identificação "Campo01") 
</td>
```

*Se for necessário poderia alterar a extensão do arquivo para salvar as informações, só preciso que o HTML recarregue este arquivo no `head` e popule alguns campos conforme os dados deste arquivo.

Ou será que existe uma solução menos complicada para trabalhar salvando informações em off?

Comment: Penso que criares um ficheiro XML seria o mais indicado

Comment: Via HTML5 você tem Local Storage à sua disposição: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/features/storage

Comment: Você precisa que essas informações sejam **portáveis**? (i.e. que você possa transportá-las do computador A pro B) Caso a resposta seja **não**, você pode usar algo como o Local Storage, o Indexed DB ou o Web SQL. Se for **sim**, talvez seja melhor usar um mini-servidor HTTP que você possa carregar num pendrive, por exemplo (há várias opções de linguagem e tecnologia para implementar isso).

Comment: OnoSendai: Não poderei usar o Google Chrome, já que nem nem todos que visualizarão o possuem. mgibsonbr: Sim preciso que as informações contidas na página possam ser visualizadas em outros computadores na mesma rede.

Comment: @Cleverson O Local Storage [é suportado em praticamente todo browser, inclusive o IE8](http://caniuse.com/#feat=namevalue-storage). Mas isso é irrelevante, já que o que você quer é um pouquinho mais complicado... Não sei se dá pra responder essa pergunta nesse formato, pois ela está meio ampla demais, mas vou tentar.

Comment: Você não poderia fazer da sua máquina um servidor web com banco de dados? (claro, isso só faz sentido se não houver restrição quanto a isso: algum tipo de política de informática).

Comment: Ou poderia utilizar um SQLite não seria pratico ?

Comment: Talvez eu esteja falando bobagem mas e se usar um arquivo um banco SQLITE com o Noje.JS? Pelo que pude perceber é assim que a plataforma de blog [Ghost](https://ghost.org/) opera.

Comment: Você de ter cuidado com o Dead-Lock, isso pode ocorrer toda vez que um usuário travou um registro em uma tabela e seu próximo passo será travar um resgistro em uma tabela relacionada à primeira, porém se este registro estiver travado por outro usuário, o primeiro usuário ficará paralisado, pois, estará esperando o segundo usuário liberar o registro em uso, para que então possa travá-lo e prosseguir sua tarefa.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Resposta curta: Não!

Elaborando um pouco mais:
**Depende** de suas necessidades. Um SGBD é uma poderosa ferramenta para persistir seus dados. Bor isso o nome BANCO, seus dados ficam guardados e protegidos e quando você precisa deles eles podem ser acessados de maneira rápida e eficaz.
Salvar dados em arquivos até funciona se você não tem muitos dados nem complexidade nas informações.

Javascript é algo que está rodando no navegador, então toda informação fica no cliente a menos que você faça algum tipo de upload desses dados. Em aplicações do mundo real não há muito sentido em colher dados de usuários que você, do lado do servidor, não vai ter acesso.

Por último, há tecnologias "na nuvem" que talvez possam lhe ser úteis e dê uma boa olhada no node.js.

**Edit 2**
Ainda não entendi inteiramente pq você quer guardar informações offline mas esse PuchDB citado no comentário parece interessante (eu não conhecia-o) pelo que puder ler "por cima" ele trabalha sincronizando dados digitados offline quando a página volta a ficar online. Mas dai ele parece que precisa do CounchDB (que por sua vez roda num servidor apache) mas vale uma olhada quando eu tiver mais tempo.

Quanto à sua necessidade de guardar pequenos pedaços de dados offline talvez vc deva usar cookies! Mas ai vai por uma senda que não costumo trilhar (meu negócio é mais lidar com grandes aplicações corporativas online)

Comment: Há controvérsias: http://pouchdb.com/

Comment: Fiz a edição. Realmente a idéia é salvar um arquivo com os dados do cliente de forma que o html consiga recarregar este arquivo em alguns campos pré-determinados.

Comment: @Cigano Morrison Mendez +1 por ter mencionado o PouchDB mas ele não precisa de um servidor Apache rodando o CounchDB?

Comment: @jean Não, ele é inspirado no Couch. É só um exemplo. Tem muitos outros.

Answer (score 9):

É desaconselhável usar o próprio sistema de arquivos em uma unidade de rede para dados que potencialmente serão alterados por duas ou mais pessoas de forma concorrente. O ideal é usar um mini webserver para isso. Para essa solução ser aplicável, há um pré-requisito entretanto:

O firewall da sua empresa permite que um computador acesse outro via porta 80? (ou outra porta não utilizada)

Caso a resposta seja "sim", eis o que sugiro:

- Use um banco de dados leve e portável, como o SQLite. [Usar esse banco como cliente-servidor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2371/215) é complicado, e no seu caso não justifica o esforço. Sendo assim, um único processo (o mini webserver) deve se conectar a esse banco, **não libere o acesso a ele via unidade de rede**. No final, todo o banco estará contido em um único arquivo, que você pode mover para outro lugar sem problemas quando necessário, fazer backups, etc.
- Desenvolva sua aplicação em um mini-webserver, também portável, que seja simples de instalar e configurar. Qual tecnologia usar, aí depende da sua expertise, mas a título de exemplo vou citar duas que eu já utilizei na prática, com sucesso:

  - Jaminid (Java Mini Daemon), usando HSQLDB (banco de dados Java puro, com opção de manter as tabelas em memória). Esse projeto está bem morto (não é atualizado desde 2006) mas ainda deve funcionar. Bom se você tem experiência com Java, e acesso a uma JVM no seu ambiente (pois nada mais é necessário instalar).
  - Django. Se você possui o Python no seu ambiente, pode-se executar o Django em modo simplificado sem a necessidade de um webserver externo. Ele integra bem com o SQLite.
- Coloque seu mini-webserver para funcionar no seu computador, e faça com que os demais computadores da rede o acessem através do seu IP e porta customizada, se necessário. Assim todos vão ler e escrever no mesmo banco, sem problemas de concorrência.

As tecnologias que citei são duas que já usei pessoalmente e confirmo que são viáveis, mas existem muitas outras (como node.js, por exemplo). Provavelmente, muitas até mais fáceis de usar. Procure por "portable web server" e você encontrará muitas opções ([exemplo](http://www.portablefreeware.com/?sc=125), [exemplo](http://www.pendriveapps.com/software/portable-web-servers/)).

Comment: Essa resposta mostra um excelente caminho para abordar o seu problema. Bancos de dados como SQLite, H2 e HSQLDB resolverão seu problema. Uma outra opção é o banco de dados Firebird (fork do Interbase, quando o mesmo era open-source).

Comment: Realmente você está correto, porém ainda sim procuro uma forma alternativa, utilizando somente arquivos fixos em locais fixos.

Answer (score 0):

Caros, após algumas horas consegui desenvolver um código digamos que simples em javascript.

Não sei se realmente é funcional, mas corresponde ao que preciso.

1 - Funciona assim: o HTML tem um input que recebe o que o cliente digita, e um "p" que irá receber a informação mais tarde.

2 - O javascript captura o que o cliente digita e com um botão salvar cria um arquivo exemplo.js com uma função "x" e as informações que preciso lá, este arquivo é armazenado nas pasta de rede.

3 - O HTML abre o arquivo exemplo.js pelo HEAD e a função "x" em onLoad pelo BODY, a função "x" faz com que o "p" receba a informação armazenada no exemplo.js.

Editarei mais tarde para ficar mais entendivel, pois tenho que sair.