# Aplicação Rails com modo offline

Tags: html5, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Em uma nova empreitada, preciso que uma aplicação simples permaneça funcionando caso a conexão com a internet seja perdida. Alguém pode me explicar como fazer isso?

Eu tinha pensado em usar os recursos de persistência do HTML5 em caso de perda da conexão, e de alguma forma que ainda não sei, fazer uma sincronização entre os banco de dados do server e do cliente quando a conexão for recuperada. Mas eis a questão. Como fazer isso usando Rails?

Encontrei alguns exemplos, mas são com arquivos estáticos referenciados no manifest de cache do html5... não sei se seria a mesma coisa no rails. Ainda não testei :(

Alguma ideia?

Comment: Esse manifest de cache é para as páginas em si (HTML/CSS/JS) continuarem funcionando se a conexão cair. Você vai precisar disso *também*. Quanto a um banco que continue funcionando *offline*, talvez o [PouchDB](http://pouchdb.com/) sirva para o que você está querendo (fonte: [esse comentário do  Cigano Morrison Mendez](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/30836/%c3%89-possivel-criar-um-banco-de-informa%c3%a7%c3%b5es-em-javascript/30842#comment57811_30842) numa pergunta relacionada). Nunca usei, mas parece fazer exatamente o que você quer: usar offline no browser e sincronizar ao ficar online.

Comment: É uma boa pergunta, na empresa onde trabalho estamos pensando nisto também, mas até agora a única alternativa encontrada foi reescrever o sistema como um aplicativo js.

Comment: Achou que esse screencast do RailsCast pode te ajudar ! [Link do screencast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/247-offline-apps-part-1)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O Application Cache do HTML5 pelo que sei é bastante complexo e portanto pode ser uma dor de cabeça de implementar.

As minhas sugestões:

- utilizar o PouchDB como já foi aqui sugerido (especialmente se usar uma base de dados NoSQL, visto que o PouchDB consegue sincronizar automaticamente).
- Outra opção que poderá ser mais compativel entre browsers seria utilizar o [localForage desenvolvido pela Mozilla](https://github.com/mozilla/localForage) que permite salvar dados offline num interface comum que usa WebSQL ou IndexedDB conforme o que está disponível.
- voltando ao HTML5 e apesar de **não estar pronto ainda** (visto que a maior parte dos browser ainda não suportam), o ServiceWorker no futuro será uma solução fantástica para este problema (como pode ser visto neste [video de apresentação](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4uQMl7mFB6g)).

Quanto à implementação do lado do servidor de Rails, para todas as soluções que sugeri o servidor apenas teria que fornecer os dados da base de dados numa página em JSON que o Javascript conseguiria aceder.

Comment: Muito obrigado! :D