# Conexao BD C# SQLite

Tags: c#, sqlite3

Tenho uma pequena aplicação em `C#` em que a base de dados foi criada no `SQLite`, inicialmente para rodar apenas localmente. Mas preciso agora dela rodando em mais 2 outras máquinas, além do servidor. Pensei em deixar uma pasta compartilhada na rede e um atalho nas outras estações apontado para a pasta; Sei das limitações do `SQLite`, mas as outras máquinas irão somente ler, não vão alterar nada no banco de dados! A questão é: Como eu faço para a string de conexão apontar para o pc que será o servidor?

Já tentei setar a string de conexão assim: `"\\ip_servidor\c$\pastaBd"` mas não deu certo! Já verifiquei as permissões da pasta compartilhada, mas está tudo ok! Mas nunca reconhece o BD.

Comment: Eu não sei como proceder do modo que você está falando, se eu fosse você colocaria o server em um servidor SQL online (tem de graça, e também tem uns bem baratos)

Answer (score 1):

Você não conseguirá acessar a pasta remota diretamente do `C#`. Para fazer isso, é preciso que tu mapeie a pasta no teu computador, e acesse a mesma a partir do endereço mapeado.

Exemplo: Faça um mapeamento da pasta `"\\ip_servidor\c$\pastaBd"` para uma letra de unidade de disco disponível, como a `"X:"`.
Após isso, na sua `connection string` utilize a unidade `"X:\"` no local de `"\\ip_servidor\c$\pastaBd"`.

A princípio é isso, utilizo essa solução no meu trabalho sem problema algum.

Answer (score 0):

Apesar do SQLite ser [Serveless](https://www.sqlite.org/serverless.html) existe algumas maneiras de se fazer isso.

Uma que eu considero bacana pois ele realmente cria um client-server service do SQLite é o SQLitening, você pode ver mais sobre ele aqui http://www.planetsquires.com/sqlite_client_server.htm e aqui http://www.sqlitening.com/support/index.php.

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2371/101