# Como compilar o banco de dados para instalar junto com uma aplicação C#?

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, banco-de-dados, sqlite

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em c#, e preciso saber se consigo compilar o banco para instalar junto com a aplicação, já vi algo por aqui falando sobre o SQLite, porém não conheço a ferramenta e não sei se ela armazena imagens, e no meu caso terei um fluxo de uma imagem por cadastro, pensei em LocalDB, porém ele armazena apenas 10GB, o que penso que vai encher logo, bom, pensei no MySQL que já utilizei para aplicações web e conheço a ferramenta, bom vão as perguntas.

1. Posso integrar o MySQL com facilidade a um projeto no Visual Studio?
2. Compensa usar o MySQL em uma aplicação desktop para cadastro?
3. Tem como instalar o banco junto com a aplicação?
4. Se não, qual um banco que tenha integração com c#, que seja grande o suficiente para um bom fluxo de cadastros e possa ser facilmente adicionado ao projeto?

Comment: Tenho visto por aí usarem instaladores de softwares(INNO SETUP e etc) e juntos, com esses instaladores os banco de dados e etc. Agora, bancos relacionais deve se ter alguns cuidados. Se na máquina do cliente não houver um instalado, o instalador vai instalar, mas é necessário de quem está adquirindo seu sistema tenha um entendimento para acompanhar a instalação. Não sei se seria uma boa. Quanto ao Sql Lite, não conheço.

Comment: Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 11):

Que fique claro que nesta resposta estou falando de aplicações puramente desktop. Não estou falando de cliente servidor onde o cliente é um executável para rodar no desktop e o banco de dados ficará no servidor para acesso por vários clientes.

No cenário cliente/servidor o aplicativo desktop será instalado separado do servidor, então a pergunta não caberia.

O cenário descrito na pergunta é para aplicações *standalone*, onde o banco de dados está intimamente ligado ao executável e só será acessado por ele.

## MySQL

Sem muitos detalhes não é fácil dar uma resposta precisa, mas de uma maneira geral não compensa usar o MySQL para uma aplicação desktop assim. Aí as demais perguntas não fariam sentido. Claro que tem como instalar junto, mas não deveria.

- O MySQL precisa ser instalado, muita coisa pode acontecer errada nesse processo. Sem falar no tamanho que deve ir junto a aplicação.
- E tem que ficar rodando. Ocupa muita memória. E usuários incautos podem facilmente comprometer seu funcionamento quando detectam coisas esquisitas no seu computador (tem como rodar sob demanda, mas não ajuda muito e pode trazer outros problemas).
- É comum precisar de manutenção, e ela não é tão simples.
- É um canhão pra matar passarinho. Muito do que ele oferece não é necessário neste cenário.
- Pode haver outros problemas em cenários específicos. Por exemplo, pode já haver um MySQL na máquina pra outra coisa. Você teria conflito ou precisaria estar preparado para lidar com isto, o que é demais para algo que deveria ser simples.

## SQLite

- O SQLite é o banco de dados padrão para aplicações desktop (não servidores).
- Ele pode fazer essencialmente tudo o que o MySQL pode. A diferença é que ele não é um servidor (ótimo neste caso), e que não pode fazer uma quantidade de escritas realmente simultâneas tão grande quanto o MySQL, mas a diferença não é brutal e no desktop isto não deve ocorrer, pelo contrário, provavelmente só será necessário fazer uma escrita por vez.

As informações sobre o componente adicional que precisa anexar ao projeto para seu uso podem ser obtidas na [página oficial](https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki) dele. Não precisa instalá-lo, ele passa fazer parte da aplicação.

Os pacotes Nuget encontrados na página de download são mais fáceis de manipular.

Ao contrário do que algumas pessoas pensam, o SQLite também pode ser usado, e eu uso com sucesso, em [cenário cliente/servidor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2371/101) (tem resposta minha lá em baixo mostrando como), mas aí pode não ser a solução mais adequada. Veja [mais sobre seu uso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/100490/101).

Se tiver dúvidas específicas, faça-as em perguntas individuais.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Estou fazendo uma aplicação desktop com o MySQL e baseado na sua resposta é mais correto, eficiente ou eficaz usar o SQLite do que o MySQL? Quais são as vantagens e desvantagens de usar o SQLite do que MySql?

Comment: Depende de cada caso. Acho que as vantagens estão aí, se for detalhar mais precisaria ser em nova pergunta. Eu atualizei para esclarecer um ponto importante, antes que haja confusão sobre o termo "aplicação desktop". Não sei qual é o seu caso.

Comment: Então vou uma pergunta sobre isso detalhando o meu caso.