# Como instalar SQLite para fazer parte de um projeto C#?

Tags: c#, .net, banco-de-dados, sqlite

Estou criando uma aplicação desktop em C# de cadastro que usará banco de dados. Qual banco de dados utilizar?

[Fui aconselhado a usar o SQLite](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/104635/101), porém não estou compreendendo muito bem como usá-lo.

1. Qual a versão do SQLite devo baixar, poderiam me ajudar com o *link*?
2. Qual gerenciador devo usar para criar o banco e as tabelas? O Visual Studio tem esta ferramenta?
3. Como integrar o banco para fazer parte do projeto, para que na instalação ele seja instalado junto?

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Comment: Olá, eu fiz uma aplicação me baseando nos exemplos [Deste Site](http://www.macoratti.net/17/04/cshp_sqlite1.htm) Uma informação, se voce quer que o campo ID seja autoincrement, não construa o arquivo com a extensão .sqlite construa com a extensao .db

Answer (score 5):

> Qual a versão do SQLite devo baixar, poderiam me ajudar com o link?

[O pacote NuGet mais recente](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SQLite). Essa versão funciona pra 32 e 64 bits.

> Qual gerenciador devo usar para criar o banco e as tabelas? O visual Studio tem esta ferramenta?

[As ferramentas para o Visual Studio estão aqui](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/23f6c55a-4909-4b1f-80b1-25792b11639e).

> Como integrar o banco para fazer parte do projeto, para que na instalação ele seja instalado junto?

O banco SQLite é um arquivo, então basta colocar este arquivo nos diretórios do projeto (normalmente o diretório `App_Data`).

No mais, aponte sua *connection string* para o arquivo. O ideal é por configuração, mas pode ser por código também.

```
new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=C:\Diretorio\banco.sqlite;Version=3;");
```

Comment: Muito obrigado Cigano Morrison Mendez, foi de grande ajuda.

Comment: @AminadabeSilva Se a resposta atendeu ao que precisa, [veja no Tour](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) quais são os próximos passos. Obrigado!

Answer (score 4):

A pergunta está ampla, genérica, vou respondê-la desta forma, se precisar de detalhes faça perguntas mais específicas com detalhes do que precisa.

Deve baixar a versão mais nova. Mas tem um monte de opção, tem que ver o que você precisa. O download pode ser feito em na [página oficial](https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki). Tem que casar com o .NET que está usando e qual sistema operacional vai rodar. É melhor pegar o [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/profiles/mistachkin). O [mais recomendado é esse](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SQLite/). Mas outros podem ser necessários conforme for desenvolvendo e querendo melhorar a experiência.

O que tem mais próximo para ajudar no Visual Studio é [isso aqui](https://www.sqlite.org/2015/sqlite-uap-3090200.vsix). Em geral as pessoas usam [ferramentas externas bem melhores](https://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=ManagementTools).

O arquivo do banco de dados é um arquivo como outro qualquer, não precisa de instalação, nada. Basta que ele seja copiado junto com o resto da aplicação.

Comment: https://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=ManagementTools já não existe.