# Modularização de sistema

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, winforms, sqlite

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema em C# com WinForms de Controle de Gado para uma fazenda, e irá se comunicar com uma balança para melhorar o processo de pesagem.

Algumas das funcionalidades são (Entrada de notas fiscais, vacinação, baixas, transferências, compras, estoque).

Estou com algumas dúvidas com relação a estrutura, pois nas fazendas não possui internet. E o gestor vai poder ter acesso aos dados através do escritório. Então não sei como fazer, pois eu teria um sistema local e um sistema web?

Eu imaginei que eu poderia ter um módulo separado para fazer a pesagem, utilizando um banco local (SQL CE, SQLite), pois acredito que não vale a pena instalar um banco SQLServer na máquina do "peão", e que depois iria sincronizar em nuvem com o sistema de gestão, após obter conexão com internet.

E as funcionalidades referente as compras, baixas, etc.. Ficaria junto com esse módulo offline?

Meu pensamento está correto, e qual banco de dados eu deveria utilizar para cada situação?

Comment: E como vai passar os dados das fazendas para o escritório?

Comment: @bigown Inicialmente eu pensei em exportas os dados para csv e carregar na máquina do escritório.

Comment: não seria possível colocar internet via satélite?

Comment: Como você já faz comunicação com a balança, acredito que saiba um mínimo sobre comunicações seriais e afins, sendo assim te sugiro uma solução tomada pela empresa em que eu trabalhava, que consiste em utilizar controladores de telemetria via GPRS. tais equipamentos podem ser encontrados em empresas como http://www.abstelemetria.com/ , vale a pena dar uma olhada!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

É muito complicado um sistema que funcione de forma isolada e ao mesmo tempo precise ser integrado. Não é fácil fazer isso funcionar corretamente e só com informações muito detalhadas daria para informar alguma coisa. Mesmo assim acho que a pergunta seria considerada ampla demais, seria praticamente uma consultoria completa.

Esse seria um caso de [condição de corrida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/159342/101) de extrema facilidade, porque você teria sistemas desconectados fazendo operações concorrentes. Então um vai lá e baixa alguma coisa, outro em outro local faz o mesmo, a hora que vai consolidar, as duas baixas conflitam e uma inviabiliza a outra. Tem formas de resolver isso, mas teria que ver o caso específico. Eu iria por um caminho que essas unidades isoladas fizessem o mínimo possível. Se for o caso até investiria em internet por satélite.

Em casos simples assim quase sempre a melhor solução é o SQLite. Tem algumas perguntas sobre o assunto.

- [Instalar banco de dados junto com a aplicação C#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/80849/101)
- [Como instalar SQLite para fazer parte de um projeto C#?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/104759/101)
- [Como compilar o banco de dados para instalar junto com uma aplicação C#?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/104635/101)

Isso é como fazer microsserviço, mas com uma latência para o dado se tornar consistente de forma muito forte.

Answer (score 1):

Uma pergunta sobre o negócio em si.
A balança é integrada ao seu sistema, ou o lançamento da pesagem é manual?

Se a balança for integrada, eu recomendaria fortemente o uso de internet, ainda que por satélite, como sugerido em outra resposta.

Se a balança não for integrada, eu acredito que você poderia pensar em uma estratégia mobile, usando um celular, ou tablet com banco de dados Sqlite que se comunica com uma WebApi. As demais funcionalidades do sistema eu recomendaria fazer com Web, pois atenderia uma eventual sede da fazenda, com internet, e também poderia estar à disposição do dono em qualquer local.

Comment: A balança é integrada com o sistema, ela implementa uma interface serial numa interface USB.