# Qual banco de dados ideal para o meu cenário?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, sqlite, firebird

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema de automação comercial (C# e Windows Forms) que poderá ser instalado em uma ou várias máquinas na mesma rede local.

Também fiz a parte *mobile* do sistema, onde é possível fazer os pedidos através de qualquer dispositivo que contenha um *browser* (uma aplicação em ASP.Net que roda no IIS da máquina/servidor). Este também poderá ser acessado por N usuários. Sei que, em relação ao IIS, existe uma limitação de conexão simultânea que varia de acordo com a edição do Windows e versão do IIS.
apesar de não entender muito bem como essa limitação funciona, esta não é minha dúvida principal (seria uma limitação de requisições ao servidor?).

Estas aplicações utilizam o SQL Server 2012 Express.

Quero tornar esse sistema o mais simples possível no momento de instalação, onde qualquer usuário com o mínimo de experiência possa fazer o download e realizar a instalação ("next...next...finish") de forma autônoma.

Pesquisei sobre o SQLite, mas vi que não se comporta bem quando utilizado por outros computadores na rede.

Também vi o SQL Server Compact, mas não utilizei pelo mesmo motivo do SQLite.

O mais perto que cheguei, pelas pesquisas que fiz, foi o Firebird.

Minha principal preocupação é com a facilidade para fazer o download e realizar a instalação do sistema. O que eu queria mesmo era manter o SQL Server, mas é muito pesado (principalmente em relação ao tamanho do download) e complicado para um usuário comum realizar a instalação.

Devo ter mais alguma preocupação quanto ao funcionamento do sistema? Firebird mesmo?

Comment: Já pensou em utilizar o Postgres? Relativamente é bem simples a instação e o download bem pequeno(54MB), comparado a outros. além disso estamos falando de um dos melhores BD existentes no mercado.

Comment: Firebird é o que tem de mais tranquilo de instalar e se administrar que já encontrei até hoje. E se for acesso local, você pode usar o modo embedded, que dispensa instalação de servidor.

Comment: O modo embarcado não resolve o problema dele.

Comment: Por que não @bigown?

Comment: @EMBarbosa porque ele precisa de concorrência, que não é possível neste modo. Se ele já acha que o SQLite não pode lidar bem com a concorrência disto (e eu acho até que pode, tenho experiência com isto, em geral vendem uma ideia errada), imagine um produto que oficialmente não dá para fazer nada de concorrência.

Comment: Só o fato de ter um banco de dados centralizado já adiciona alguma complexidade ao deploy, fica bem difícil o *next next finish* - alguém terá no mínimo que informar qual será o servidor. Eu ficaria com o SQL Server mesmo, que tem instalação, configuração e gerenciamento facílimo comparado a outros SGBDs; além de toda robustez que você vai precisar.

Comment: @bigown mas ele não disse que está tendo dificuldade de concorrência, apenas que quer algo mais simples de ser instalado. De qualquer forma, a versão mais recente do Firebird permite sim acesso concorrente do BD, desde que feito na mesma máquina. http://stackoverflow.com/a/32903077/460775

Comment: @EMBarbosa Está implícito. Ele disse que o SQLite é problemático. Se for para usar sem concorrência, ele é a melhor solução que existe pronta. O FB embarcado tem pouca ou nenhuma utilidade como banco de dados,ele serve só como arquivador.

Comment: @bigown agora você já está trollando... deixa pra lá...

Comment: @ítalo Camilo, Cada cliente(empresa que você atende) tem um servidor, onde fica o IIS e o SQL Server (2 servidores?) e as diversas máquinas clientes acessam o servidor do IIS para usar a aplicação, correto? Qual a versão do Windows instalada no servidor? e qual a configuração do servidor?Existe existe uma parte dos clientes(desktops) que acessam o banco com Windows Forms, correto?

Answer (score 3):

Há ainda a possibilidade do [SQL Server Express LocalDb](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/hh510202(v=sql.120).aspx), que é praticamente seu SQL Server, mas baseado em um único arquivo MDF. O impacto sobre seu sistema será muito pequeno.

Outra coisa que você poderia fazer é oferecer seu sistema na nuvem. Não sei se você já pensou na possibilidade, mas poupa o cliente de fazer ele mesmo a instalação. [Azure é uma opção](https://azure.microsoft.com/pt-br/).

Answer (score 3):

O Firebird que não precisa instalar não é nada adequado para o que deseja, é absurdamente mais limitado que o SQLite. A versão que funciona bem (ainda que pouco escalável até a versão que eu conheço) tem que instalar, cairia no mesmo problema de instalar o SQL Server Express.

É possível usar o [SQL Server LocalDB](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-express-localdb?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=sql-server-ver15), mas ele não é adequado para vários cenários. Ele continua pesado para baixar e rodar, só não precisa de um processo de instalação complicado. Você precisaria analisar se é adequado pro seu cenário.

[O SQLite é bem adequado para muitos casos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/100490/101), mesmo em rede, adotando um esquema de [cliente-servidor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2371/101), desde que o programador saiba o que está fazendo. Em geral ele acaba não sendo recomendado porque o programador, em geral, não sabe o que está fazendo. Ele é bem mais escalável do que as pessoas imaginam, e pode se comportar até melhor que o SQL Server Express em alguns cenários.

Outras soluções são menos adequadas ainda para o que está pensando. Ou invista o que for necessário para rodar o SQLite, ou aceite que terá que usar o SQL Server mesmo (partindo do princípio que não deseja fazer mudanças profundas no sistema), optando pelo Express ou LocalDB dependendo do seu caso.

Comment: Tenho que discordar, em especial da parte "Outras soluções são menos adequadas ainda para o que está pensando". Você não tem como analisar todas as outras soluções para saber que todas elas são menos adequadas.

Comment: Tecnicamente é verdade. Mas buscar soluções fora do padrão para alguém que procura algo simples é por si só uma impedimento, não estou só analisando o lado técnico, mas a condição apresentada na pergunta me deixa inferir que ele não vai querer soluções que criam mais complicadores. Só o fato de usar algo fora do padrão é um enorme complicador. O próprio uso do SQLite talvez seja um complicador e deixo isto claro na resposta. Falei dele porque estava na pergunta. Fiz uma análise do que está na pergunta. Se tem coisas fora da pergunta que dificultam ou facilitam a escolha, eu não posso dizer.

Comment: Por outro lado ninguém pode afirmar que qualquer solução é adequada para ele. Então olhando por esse ângulo, todas as respostas estarão erradas. Eu dei a melhor resposta possível, nem fechando demais o leque, nem deixando aberto demais.

Comment: Verdade. Por isso perguntas deste tipo nem são mais aceitas no SOen. São muito baseadas em opiniões ao invés de em dados realísticos. De qualquer maneira, só quis deixar registrado que discordo porque não temos informações suficientes.