# SQLite sendo acessado remotamente

Tags: android, sqlite

Seria possível de criar uma conexão do App no Android com o serviço do SQLite com PC Local? Não falo de um banco de dados dentro do próprio Android, mas sim comunicando-se com PC mesmo.

Comment: O que é um PC local?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sim, é possível, mas não recomendável.

Qualquer acesso direto ao arquivo é problemático, o sistema operacional tem dificuldade de lidar com acessos remotos concorrentes diretos. Além disso não é tão simples cuidar da segurança ao acesso a esse arquivo e tem chance de acabar expondo o computador onde está o arquivo do SQLite.

Obviamente que estou considerando que o computador pode ser facilmente localizado na rede. Tem uma série de preocupações a serem observadas que dependeria de um estudo mais profundo do assunto. Não dá para seguir receita de bolo, e acho que nem tem uma, por bons motivos.

O que é mais recomendável é o acesso ser feito através de uma aplicação intermediária no computador onde está localizado o arquivo SQLite e essa aplicação é que faz o acesso ao DB.

- Existe a possibilidade de [criar uma aplicação própria](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2371/101) para isso e usar um protocolo de comunicação próprio entre a aplicação servidora e o cliente no Android:

  Só é recomendado para programadores experientes ou que tenha bom domínio da computação. Se não souber fazer tem vários pontos para dar errado.
- Ou pode usar um servidor web padrão e criar apenas a aplicação que faz o acesso ao SQLite de forma simples e entregar para o servidor HTTP cuidar da comunicação com o Android:

  - há riscos de fazer errado, mas não é tão complicado;
  - tem receitas de bolo (para serem seguidas cegamente e a solução não ficar tão boa, a começar porque está sendo escolhida porque é fácil e não porque é a melhor);
  - e quase todo mundo pode ajudar porque isso é uma solução padrão adotada;
  - mas pode não ser a melhor performance se não precisa do acesso via HTTP.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Como não reconheço serviço com SQLite gratuito tivesse essa ideia tola de fazer isso. Obrigado

Comment: Poderia ensinar a realizar a conexão do Android (Virtual) com o PostgreSQL na máquina local? Obrigado!

Comment: Aí você tem que fazer uma nova pergunta.

Comment: Link: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/155435/android-como-conectar-android-virtual-com-postgresql-na-m%c3%a1quina-local