# Como conectar Android Virtual com PostGreSQL na Máquina Local?

Tags: android, postgresql, android-eclipse

Bom dia,

Estou tentando criar uma conexão do `Android Virtual` criado
no `Eclipse ADT` com `JDBC do PostGreSQL 9.1`. Como meu conhecimento 
em `Android` é pouco gastei muito tempo tentando conectar e não tive
sucesso algum.

```
public String conectarDB() throws ExecutionException {

    // Variáveis
    try {
        String driver = "com.postgresql.Driver";
        String url = "jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/database";
        String user = "postgres";
        String pass = "#Servicedesk#@!1";

     // Conectar
        try {
            Class.forName(driver);
            Connection con = null;
            con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
            return ("Conexão: Funcionando!");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return ("Erro com Database!");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return ("Erro com JDBC!");
        }

    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return ("Conexão: Erro no envio de Conexão!");
    }

}
```

Comment: Você está recebendo algum dos erros?

Comment: Não... Apenas exibe: "Conexão: Erro Database!"

Comment: Então você sabe que é uma SQLException, tente trocar localhost por 127.0.0.1

Comment: Se for String driver = "org.postgresql.Driver"; = Erro com JDBC
Se for String driver = "com.postgresql.Driver"; = Erro com Database

Comment: Precisa configurar algo no AndroidManifest.xml? Para Android Virtual reconhece alguma coisa?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sofri muito com esse erro porém consegui resolver, era muito simples, faltava a permissão de acesso a internet no AndroidManifest.xml

Basta adicionar a seguinte linha ao AndroidManifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

Apos isso talvez você encontre problemas ao conectar ao banco, caso não tenha configurado o acesso previamente.

Certifique-se também de adicionar a biblioteca do PostgreSQL ao projeto (Android Studio):

1 - Clique com o botão direito na raiz do projeto;

2 - Open Module Settings;

3 - Aba Dependencies;

4 - Adicione uma biblioteca em "+" e busque a "postgresql" mais recente;

5 - Dê OK e espere sincronizar.

Comment: Excepcional. Vou testar. Obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

Não é possível realizar conexões do Android diretamente para um banco de dados. Para isso é necessário consumir um web service.

Neste site há um exemplo de criação e consumo de um web service:

https://www.b4x.com/android/forum/threads/connect-android-to-mysql-database-tutorial.8339/