# Laravel e banco de dados SQLite

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, laravel, sqlite, firebird

Pense comigo, tem *server* Laravel com um banco de dados SQLite configurado, o acesso a esse banco em tese é pra ser mais rápido, já que está no próprio servidor. Segue o exemplo:

usuario -> servidor (o banco já está no servidor, então é menos uma requisição)

**usuario -> servidor -> banco de dados**

Seriam 3 caminhos com um servidor externo, tipo um MySQL, Firebird, como o SQLite já está no Laravel, é pra puxar os dados mais rápido, certo?

Qual seria o problema ao usar SQLite?

Comment: Verifique a quantidade de pessoas (estimativas) que usariam o sistema feito no Laravel, o sistema basicamente é pra qual tipo de finalidade?. Se o sistema for para um trabalho custoso não é recomendável utilizar SQLite, basicamente precisa que essa pergunta nos traga um foco, ou seja, um cenário de estudo, acho eu que faltou relatar essas informações. Basicamente eu utilizaria MySQL que é um servidor muito bom e em todas as hospedagem e serviços web tem ... como está com Laravel criaria todas as migrations que é um facilitador na hora de criar sua base de dados nas hospedagens.

Comment: Seria uma aplicação de poucos usos, por isso pensei no SQLite, mas creio que vou me padronizar num FireBird ou MySql mesmo. Devido serem mais próprios pra usar quando estiver uma enorme banda de dados

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Essa presunção que o SQLite está no servidor ou que outro não está e que isto é mais rápido é algo incorreto. O fato do banco de dados estar no servidor ou não, depende. [Nem é certo que o SQLite esteja](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/150975/101), mas geralmente está. Os demais tem mais chance de não estar, mas quase sempre está e se você quer que esteja então estará, porque acha que não?

Nem vou entrar na questão que esse ganho todo que acha que terá nem sempre é verdade.

Talvez esteja usando termos errados, ou até não entenda o funcionamento das coisas, mas para tomar decisões certas precisa entender tudo isso, caso contrário terá que contar com uma pessoa aleatória na internet dizendo o que é bom para você.

O normal é SQLite estar no mesmo processo, mas ele é um banco de dados e se tiver que fazer esse esqueminha que fez o SQLite também é `usuario -> servidor -> banco de dados`, ainda que isso nem faça sentido.

Não sei se o SQLite já está no Laravel, mas vou confiar em você. E daí? O que isso muda a não ser o fato de não precisar pegar em outro lugar para por ali? Não, isso não faz ser mais rápido, isso muda nada, sua presunção está bem equivocada.

E o que isto importa se tem inúmeros outros fatores que vão influenciar a performance muito mais que isso, inclusive boa parte deles tem a ver com sua capacidade de usar o banco de dados direito e fazer códigos adequados.

O fato de [já ter um servidor fica bem mais fácil usar o SQLite](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2371/101).

[Já respondi sobre o uso do SQLite](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/100490/101). O SQLite não pode ser usado em todos cenários, mas pode ser usado em bem mais do que as pessoas acham, se elas souberem o que estão fazendo e estiverem dispostas resolver algumas questões que tem nele conforme citado no *link*.

Comment: Complementando, o acesso ao SQLite no PHP é feito a partir da extensão do php-sqlite3. A extensão já faz tudo, então temos a impressão que não precisamos instalar mais nada, e o Laravel torna de forma mais fácil a troca do servidor de banco de dados para diferentes finalidades. Um caso de uso é usar o sqlite in-memory para testes automatizados, por exemplo. Nesse cenário ele é mais rápido que um banco tradicional pois não existe a persistência no disco, mas você não quer um banco de dados que não seja persistente, certo? :)

Answer (score -1):

Na verdade a velocidade não está somente nos saltos entre recursos, mas em sua estruturação dos modelos também, na madeira como salvamos os índices e etc.

O SQLite é muito bom para várias coisas, porém se você começar a ter vários relacionamentos e tipos mais complexos de dados, ele não suporta, ele somente suporta primitivos simples.

Fora isso ele é bloqueante por padrão, ou seja, se vc tá inserindo algo em uma tabela ele vai dar lock naquela tabela, você pode tirar isso, até pra aumentar a velocidade, mas só de tirar ele perde a atomicidade.

Você pode ter um MySql rodando no mesmo servidor do laravel por exemplo, pra diminuir a latência entre sua aplicação e o banco de dados, mas é imperceptível muitas vezes.

A escolha do banco vai muito do que vc espera do banco, velocidade, relacionamentos complexos, flexibilidade e etc.

Comment: Não negativei a resposta, ainda, mas você poderia explicar melhor o que é `se você começar a ter vários relacionamentos e tipos mais complexos de dados, ele não suporta, ele somente suporta primitivos simples`? E `se vc tá inserindo algo em uma tabela ele vai dar lock naquela tabela` a ideia geral até tem razão, mas sem explicação melhor dá a entender coisa errada, e não é travamento de tabela não, isso está errado. `você pode tirar isso, até pra aumentar a velocidade, mas só de tirar ele perde a atomicidade` Tem certeza?