# Qual SGBD utilizar para que possa ser instalado no computador do cliente para rodar uma aplicação C#?

Tags: c#, banco-de-dados, entity-framework, aplicação-desktop

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema pequeno em C# que futuramente será implementado em computadores de clientes, acessando um banco de dados local.

Inicialmente eu ia utilizar o SQL Server, mas teria que instalá-lo junto do sistema, e este fica sendo meio pesado para apenas um sistema simples.

Queria uma indicação de SGBD que seja bom e simples e leve, para usar como banco nessa aplicação C#. Preciso que apenas um computador esteja com o banco de dados e os demais PCs com o sistema encontrem e usem este banco pela rede.

Comment: Mas esse computador vai ter que servir como servidor, certo? Para a BD ser acessada por outros PC's

Comment: Sim. Preciso de um servidor com o BD e os demais pcs devem acessá-lo. Nisso preciso de um SGBD leve

Comment: Eu apostaria no SQL Express, leve e totalmente compatível com C#

Comment: Sugiro o próprio SQL Server, é simples de instalar, e o mais tranquilo para utilizar com entity framework. Não é necessário instalar nas máquinas clients, somente no servidor. De qualquer forma não dá pra uma única resposta correta para essa pergunta....muito ampla.

Comment: @Alisson eu pensei nisso, mas achei que não é ampla, dá em uma resposta para colocar todas opções, facilmente. Ainda vou melhorar minha.

Comment: @PatrickCardoso Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 8):

Pelo cenário descrito a solução seria o [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/), ele não precisa instalar, vai embutido na própria aplicação.

Algumas pessoas usam o [LocalDB](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/working-with-sql?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397), mas ele costuma ser menos adequado que o SQLite para acesso remoto. O mesmo pode ser dito do [SQL Server Compac](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Compact)t que é praticamente obsoleto.

O problema é que não pode ter outras aplicações externas acessando o mesmo banco de dados do SQLite. Você teria que [escrever um servidor de aplicação para controlar o acesso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2371/101). Eu gosto da ideia, mas não é todo mundo que sabe fazer isto. Não existe almoço grátis. Minha preferência é escrever um servidor para ele.

Existem algumas outras opções que caem no mesmo problema. Poderia fazer

Se deseja um servidor pronto, não tem o que fazer, terá que instalar. O que pode fazer é automatizar a instalação. O [SQL Server Express](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-editions-express?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) é uma opção gratuita e interessante, mas ele possui limitações de uso. Algumas acham fácil instalar o [Firebird](https://firebirdsql.org/). Mas cuidado para não instalar o embarcado que é extremamente limitado e não pode ser usado para acesso simultâneo. Mesmo a versão completa costuma ter problemas de escala. Depois disto só personalizando uma forma de instalar o MySQL ou PostgreSQL que podem ser montado do jeito que deseja.

Na verdade se quer um servidor não vejo tanta desvantagem assim ter que instalá-lo. É muito mais importante ter opção sem instalar em cliente desktop ou mobile, aí o SQLite é disparado a melhor opção. Mesmo com servidor em geral minha opção é pelo SQLite sempre ele que aguenta.

Estas opções permitem o uso com o Entity Framework. Podem existir opções que não são compatíveis.

Existe uma certa dicotomia entre não instalar e ter acesso externo. A não ser soluções malucas ou totalmente construída por você, sói o SQLite adaptado para funcionar como servidor resolverá. Na prática mesmo esse caso terá que instalar o seu servidor.

Fora isto fazer uso de nuvem é a única saída para não ter que instalar o banco de dados. Claro que isto tem suas desvantagens também.

Se quer um banco de dados como o SQL Server completo, instalar é o menor dos problemas. Inclusive tem que comprá-lo.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Se tiver algum erro favor informar para eu melhorar. Acho estranho a reposta que dá mais opções, incluindo as mesmas de outras respostas positivadas ter um negativo.

Comment: Eu já li a respeito do SQLite, parece ser uma opção interessante quando se pretende ter um banco de dados embutido com a aplicação, se não me engano as aplicações para android utilizam ele para guardar dados no dispositivo, e alguma API para armazenar em um servidor. Será que tem alguma biblioteca/provider para SQLite para trabalhar com o Entity Framework?

Comment: Tem sim, ele tem muito suporte. Ele se tornou o DB embarcado quase oficial da Microsoft.

Answer (score 5):

Olá, uma vez que tive a necessidade de criar aplicação simples em que o usuário não precisasse de usar um banco e solucionei com o `SQL Lite`. Ele é um banco de dados simples que não precisa ser instalado pelo usuário final.

Se não precisar exatamente disso, sugiro ler sobre o `SQL Express`, que é uma versão mais compacta do `SQL Server`, perfeita para aplicações menores.

Comment: E como usar o SQLite em outros computadores conforme a pergunta pede? E se o limite do SQl Server Express não atender a aplicação?

Answer (score 4):

> *Queria uma indicação de SGBD que seja bom e simples e leve, para usar como banco nessa aplicação C#. Preciso que apenas um computador esteja com o banco de dados e os demais pcs com o sistema encontrem e usem este banco pela rede.*

Neste caso você instala o software de acesso ao banco de dados junto com a aplicação e, no computador que optar por funcionar (também) como *servidor de banco de dados*, você pode instalar o SQL Server Express. ODBC é uma opção para conexão do aplicativo ao banco de dados.

Somente em um dos computadores será necessário instalar o SGBD.

A edição Express do SQL Server possui algumas limitações, principalmente de tamanho máximo de cada banco de dados (até 10 GB) e máximo de memória por instância (1 GB, na prática 1.410 MB).

Na linha de software livre você encontra, dentre vários, o [MariaDB](https://mariadb.org/).

Sugestão de leitura:

- [Comparison of SQL Server Compact, SQLite, SQL Server Express and
  LocalDB](http://erikej.blogspot.com.br/2011/01/comparison-of-sql-server-compact-4-and.html)
- [Edições e recursos com suporte do SQL Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/sql-server/editions-and-components-of-sql-server-2016)  (atenção para a edição Express)
- [Database Connectionstrings](http://www.dofactory.com/reference/connection-strings)

Comment: No caso, quando você se refere á "software de acesso ao banco de dados", seria este ODBC? Teria que ter este instalado nas estações para que elas possam se comunicar com o servidor, isso?

Comment: @PatrickCardoso: Me refiro a "software cliente do SGBD", isto é, aquele que permite estabelecer a conexão do aplicativo com o banco de dados remoto. ODBC é uma das opções, caso no aplicativo seja utilizada conexão ODBC. Isto varia conforme o SGBD, mas ODBC é quase _universal_. E sim, o "software cliente do SGBD" deve ser instalado em cada estação de trabalho, junto com o aplicativo. Geralmente é um _driver_ ou _provedor_.

Answer (score -3):

Algumas opções populares de SGBDs que podem ser instalados em computadores de clientes incluem o Microsoft SQL Server, o MySQL, o PostgreSQL e o SQLite.

Answer (score -5):

Olá,

Como disse que era um SGBD leve e precisa de um servidor que tenhas essa funções todas eu aconselho: o **XAMPP** é um servidor que contem Apache, MariaDB (base de dados) , PHPMyAdmin (pode ser o seu SGBD apesar de eu usar a MariaDB em terminal), PHP, Perl e está disponível para a maioria dos SO's.

https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html

Espero ter ajudado